# Passing extra data while passing through serializer django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am looking to pass extra data in the serializer but unable to do so. Below is my code
views.py

```
device_id = request.META.get('HTTP_DEVICE', '')
user_data = request.data
serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
```

I want to pass device id as well with user_data. I tried a dictionary but it is not getting the data. Suggest a syntax

Comment: Please post your UserSerializer code.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a context to your Serializer like:

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data, context={'YOUR_CONTEXT': CONTEXT_OBJ})
```

And then get it in your validate method like:

```
    def validate(self, data):
        CONTEXT_OBJ = self.context.get('YOUR_CONTEXT')
        ...
```

I hope this may help you!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're question lacks any substantial detail about your model declarations or serializers. However, this still looks wrong. You should not be doing something like this.

Instead, your model should be something like this

```
class User(model):

     # declarations of id, account_name, HTTP_DEVICE, etc.
```

And then your serializer,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'HTTP_DEVICE', 'account_name')
```

Then, the serializer will have all of these fields.

Please reference the [django rest framework documentation.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)

Comment: I have got everything exactly the way you said just need to know how to pass both device_id with user_data into serializer. Tried a dictionary like this but it did'nt work.                                                                               queryset = {'user_data': request.data, 'device_id': request.META.get('HTTP_DEVICE', '')}